# how should I use a name in a local internet network instead of ip address

Tags: node.js, nginx

I've wrote a node.js server app and ran it on my university local internet. I need others to connect not using my ip address.
my computer system has Ubuntu 16.04 os
I know that address should be
    http://mypchostname:port
but this doesn't work either.
I've already tried changing my device host name using
    sudo hostname new-hostname

and I've already installed nginx on my system. I changed my /etc/hostname file content to myhostname and /etc/hosts to
    127.0.0.1    myhostname
    127.0.1.1    myhostname

and I add that to my listen function

```
listen(PORT,"myhostname",34, function(){
//Callback triggered when server is successfully listening. Hurray!
console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work in our university local network
please help me i'm in a big hurry

Comment: Are all of the systems on the same subnet ? What is you local IP ? To be able to fix the issue, we need to know more about your network configurations.

Comment: This is not a programming question. But I'll give you a hint: changing hostnames on your machine won't change anything on the intranet (LAN). You need a router with DNS capablities where you can add a hostname that points to your computer's IP address. Ask your Network admin to set it up for you.

Comment: Did you check your firewall settings? The port you are using may be blocked.

Comment: @er-han it works with the http://ipaddress:port but not with http://hostname:sameport